# Move rows to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried using PIVOT and other methods to fix a problem, but I seem to be stuck.

```
CustomerID  Question    Answer
...........................................................
469494      Q111        Mottok e-post                 
469494      Q125        Ja                            
469494      Q112        Ja                            
469494      Q113        Ingeniør eller bachelor i tekn
469494      Q16         6 Meget bra
```

I need each customer row to inlude all answers, and the columns to be the value of Question key. Like This:

```
CustomerID  Q111          Q125    Q112     Q113                            (etc)
.........................................................................................
469494      Mottok e-post Ja      Ja       Ingeniør eller bachelor i tekn
```

There are multiple customers answering. And some answers are freetext.

My main problem here is that The Questions - and ofcourse - the answers are dynamic. They are answering a questionnaire, and this is a report that should be able to run and extract info for a specific questionnaire, with different Question keys and number of questions may also vary.

I didn't manage to do this with the PIVOT function, as the values differ.

Comment: Search for dynamic PIVOT, with Dynamic-SQL you can achive this

Comment: Thanks. I'll try again. I did a search, but I didn't quite manage to pull it off. I might have missed a connection with the examples and my specific needs.

Comment: The clue is you use your normal PIVOT query and change `SELECT col1, col2, col3, ... FROM .. PIVOT (FOR .. IN (col1, col2, col3)` and you need to change hardcoded `col1, col2, col3` with `@cols` variable and `EXEC` it

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure your clue will help me get this right.

Comment: While this is definitely possible to do with PIVOT and dynamic sql, I would probably argue the database server is probably not the best place to to this. This is often better handled elsewhere, f.ex. a web page / application actually presenting the data to the user - if such a thing is present.